# How to generate range(sequence) of values from given two input values

Tags: xslt

Please suggest, to generate range of numbers from two values.

I used call-template methods. Please advice. I am using XSLT 2.

XML:

```
<article>
 <range>3-7</range>
</article>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="//range">
 <xsl:variable name="var1" select="substring-before(., '-')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="var2" select="substring-after(., '-')"/>

 <range>
      <xsl:attribute name="ID">
           <xsl:call-template name="tmpPageRange">
                <xsl:with-param name="stPage" select="$var1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="lstPage" select="$var2"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="presentvalue" select="$var1"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </range>
</xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="tmpPageRange">
           <xsl:param name="stPage"/>
           <xsl:param name="lstPage"/>
           <xsl:param name="presentvalue"/>

           <xsl:if test="number($stPage) &lt; number($lstPage)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($presentvalue, ' ')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="tmpPageRange">
                     <xsl:with-param name="stPage" select="number($stPage) + 1"/>
                     <xsl:with-param name="lstPage"/>
                     <xsl:with-param name="presentvalue" select="$stPage"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OutPut:

```
<range ID="3 4 5 6 7">3-7</range>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:template match="article/range">
    <range>
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:for-each select="xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[1]) to xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[2])">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </range>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your perfect and quick suggestion. One small request, can we do this thru call-template method also?, please suggest what is wrong with my coding. Once again thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This being XSLT 2 you can replace the whole `for-each` with `<xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[1]) to xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[2])" separator=" " />`

Comment: In fact, space is the default `separator` for a `value-of` with a `select` attribute, so you don't even need that explicitly (though IMO it makes the intention clearer).

Comment: @IanRoberts, that's great.. what if someone wants the spaces collapsed? I mean, is it possible with just using `value-of`?

Comment: Then you specify `separator=""`

Comment: @IanRoberts, Thanks a lot for your value-able suggestions for simple and perfect XSLT coding.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from [Lingamurthy CS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26886008/592139), there are various shortcuts that XSLT 2.0 offers that allow you to shorten this substantially.  In fact for your specific requirement you can roll it right the way up into an attribute value template:

```
<range ID="{xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[1]) to xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[2])}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</range>
```

The XSLT 2.0 rule for [converting a sequence of atomic values to a string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-simple-content) in an AVT is to convert each item to a string individually and then output the resulting sequence separated by spaces.  If you wanted a different separator (or no separator at all) then you could use `xsl:attribute`, which can take a `separator` attribute to override the default (single space) separator, e.g.

```
<range>
  <xsl:attribute name="ID"
           select="xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[1]) to xs:integer(tokenize(.,'-')[2])"
           separator="," />
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</range>
```

would produce `<range ID="3,4,5,6,7">3-7</range>`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. +1 for your short and perfect XSLT2 code.