# Creating Author Index with the help of xsl:for-each-group method

Tags: xslt

Suggest for grouping (sort) the Authors and other info within grouped section where section having first character of the author names (fnm), i.e., all names start by 'D' are should be listed within D....

And also how to insert space between fnm and snm (content of 'current-grouping-key()' method).

See my comments in required output file for required text.

XML:

```
<root>
<article>
    <fm>
        <title>The <i>article</i> 1</title>
        <author><fnm>Kishan</fnm><snm>TR</snm></author>
        <author><fnm>Rudramuni</fnm><snm>TP</snm></author>
        <articleInfo>
            <pii>PII:001</pii>
        </articleInfo>
    </fm>
</article>
<article>
    <fm>
        <title>The <b>article</b> 2</title>
        <author><fnm>Likhith</fnm><snm>MD</snm></author>
        <author><fnm>Kowshik</fnm><snm>MD</snm></author>
        <author><fnm>Kishan</fnm><snm>TR</snm></author>
        <articleInfo>
            <pii>PII:002</pii>
        </articleInfo>
    </fm>
</article>
<article>
    <fm>
        <title>The <bi>article</bi> 3</title>
        <author><fnm>Deepu</fnm><snm>JS</snm></author>
        <author><fnm>Kishan</fnm><snm>TR</snm></author>
        <articleInfo>
            <pii>PII:003</pii>
        </articleInfo>
    </fm>
</article>
<article>
    <fm>
        <title>The <bi>article</bi> 4</title>
        <author><fnm>Divya</fnm><snm>JS</snm></author>
        <articleInfo>
            <pii>PII:004</pii>
        </articleInfo>
    </fm>
</article>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
   <index>
        <!--xsl:for-each-group select="article" group-by="substring(fm/author, 1,1)">
           <index-sec><title><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></title-->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="article" group-by="fm/author">
          <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
              <index-entry>
                   <index-heading><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></index-heading>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </index-entry>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
           <!--/index-sec>
        </xsl:for-each-group-->
   </index>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
   <intra-ref href="{self::title/following-sibling::articleInfo/pii}"><xsl:apply-templates/></intra-ref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="articleInfo|author"/>

<xsl:template match="article|fm"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required outPut:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<index>
 <index-sec><title>D</title><!--Required-->
    <index-entry>
       <index-heading>DeepuJS</index-heading><!--How to insert space between  FNM and SNM, i.e., Deep JS, like this for all Authors-->
       <intra-ref href="PII:003">The <bi>article</bi> 3</intra-ref>
    </index-entry>
    <index-entry>
       <index-heading>DivyaJS</index-heading>
       <intra-ref href="PII:004">The <bi>article</bi> 4</intra-ref>
    </index-entry>
</index-sec><!--Required-->
<index-sec><title>K</title><!--Required-->  
    <index-entry>
       <index-heading>KishanTR</index-heading>
       <intra-ref href="PII:001">The <i>article</i> 1</intra-ref>
       <intra-ref href="PII:002">The <b>article</b> 2</intra-ref>
       <intra-ref href="PII:003">The <bi>article</bi> 3</intra-ref>
    </index-entry>
    <index-entry>
       <index-heading>KowshikMD</index-heading>
       <intra-ref href="PII:002">The <b>article</b> 2</intra-ref>
    </index-entry>
</index-sec><!--Required-->
<index-sec><title>L</title><!--Required-->  
    <index-entry>
       <index-heading>LikhithMD</index-heading>
       <intra-ref href="PII:002">The <b>article</b> 2</intra-ref>
    </index-entry>
</index-sec><!--Required-->
 <index-sec><title>R</title><!--Required-->  
    <index-entry>
       <index-heading>RudramuniTP</index-heading>
       <intra-ref href="PII:001">The <i>article</i> 1</intra-ref>
    </index-entry>
</index-sec><!--Required-->
</index>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to group `author`s twice, once by the first letter of `fnm` and then by `concat(fnm,snm)`. Here is my try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <index>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//author" group-by="substring(fnm,1,1)">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <index-sec>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </title>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(fnm,snm)">
                    <xsl:sort select="number(substring-after(../articleInfo/pii,':'))" data-type="number"/>
                    <index-entry>
                        <index-heading>
                            <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
                        </index-heading>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </index-entry>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </index-sec>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </index>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="author">
    <intra-ref href="{../articleInfo/pii}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../title"/>
    </intra-ref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Lingamurthy, for second for-each-group, I coded like "<xsl:for-each-group select="."> (first one as 'fm/author', second one as self while testing). Small clarification, how space inserting between fnm and fnm. Once thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: For space insertion, if you remember IanRoberts' answer from day-before yesterday: [Adding separator using value-of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885877/how-to-generate-rangesequence-of-values-from-given-two-input-values/26886008)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, value-of select by default will have space as separators for multiples.